# How can I get a list of Git local branches, which are not already pushed to GitHub?

Tags: git, git-branch

Given:

- I have local some branches, and some of them are pushed my account to GitHub
- but there are some local branches which I don't have pushed

How can I list the unpushed branches?

Also possible:

List all local branches (pushed/non pushed) with the existing remote visible.

I tried the command `remote show origin` already and there I see the remote branches, but there are the local unpushed branches that are not listed :(

```
git remote -v show origin
```

This shows only my local branches:

```
git branch -vv
```

## Added 2020-05-06:

### Expected Result:

I see for all my local branches the associated origin branches:

*Note: this expected result is manually created*

```
* master                               [origin/master: 60 hinterher]
  muescha/feature/npm-readme
  muescha/fix/agility-format           [origin/muescha/fix/agility-format: ... ]
  muescha/fix/anchor-tags-in-glossary
  muescha/fix/brand-webpack            [origin/muescha/fix/brand-webpack: ... ]
  muescha/fix/claudinary-code-block
  muescha/fix/claudinary-format
  muescha/fix/claudinary-optional
  muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell       [origin/muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell: ... ]
  muescha/fix/gatsby-cloud-brand-names
  muescha/fix/la-days-kim              [origin/muescha/fix/la-days-kim: ... ]
  muescha/fix/receipes-changes
  muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8
  muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix        [origin/muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix: ... ]
```

So that I see which branch is not already pushed to GitHub.

In my case these branches do not have an branch on GitHub and only local branches:

*Note: this expected result is manually created*

```
  muescha/feature/npm-readme
  muescha/fix/anchor-tags-in-glossary
  muescha/fix/claudinary-code-block
  muescha/fix/claudinary-format
  muescha/fix/claudinary-optional
  muescha/fix/gatsby-cloud-brand-names
  muescha/fix/receipes-changes
  muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8
```

### Current Status:

#### Branches on GitHub

https://github.com/muescha/gatsby/branches

```
# Default branch
master                         | Updated 2 days ago by wardpeet   | Default

# Your branches
muescha/fix/la-days-kim        | Updated 16 days ago by muescha   | 288/3
muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell | Updated 14 days ago by gatsbybot | 187/7
muescha/fix/brand-webpack      | Updated 12 days ago by gatsbybot | 127/4
muescha/fix/agility-format     | Updated 20 days ago by muescha   | 288/4
muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix  | Updated 2 months ago by muescha  | 901/1
```

#### git remote --verbose

```
$ git remote --verbose
gatsby    https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby.git (fetch)
gatsby    https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby.git (push)
origin    https://github.com/muescha/gatsby.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/muescha/gatsby.git (push)
```

#### git config --local -l

```
$ git config --local -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/muescha/gatsby.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
remote.gatsby.url=https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby.git
remote.gatsby.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gatsby/*
pull.rebase=true
branch.muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix.remote=origin
branch.muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix.merge=refs/heads/muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell.remote=origin
branch.muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell.merge=refs/heads/muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell
branch.muescha/fix/brand-webpack.remote=origin
branch.muescha/fix/brand-webpack.merge=refs/heads/muescha/fix/brand-webpack
branch.muescha/fix/la-days-kim.remote=origin
branch.muescha/fix/la-days-kim.merge=refs/heads/muescha/fix/la-days-kim
branch.muescha/fix/agility-format.remote=origin
branch.muescha/fix/agility-format.merge=refs/heads/muescha/fix/agility-format
```

#### git branch -vv

```
$ git branch -vv
* master                               5a4f7a1e7 [origin/master: 60 hinterher] chore(starters): add gatsby-typescript-starter-minimalist (#23393)
  muescha/feature/npm-readme           f07b4db3c fix brand names
  muescha/fix/agility-format           06d9f8ad0 fix add language to code block
  muescha/fix/anchor-tags-in-glossary  505e5268e fixes links
  muescha/fix/brand-webpack            d0758d81f change brand names in yaml files
  muescha/fix/claudinary-code-block    b6eca1f0f fix add language to code block
  muescha/fix/claudinary-format        546fbdfc5 fix move out of prefix section
  muescha/fix/claudinary-optional      03d41affc fix move other optionals out of prefix section
  muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell       df7ad898c add shell
  muescha/fix/gatsby-cloud-brand-names cad8ed156 fix brand names
  muescha/fix/la-days-kim              623c6d28c change tags indent
  muescha/fix/receipes-changes         f788c2d0d change brand names, local links
  muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8            bf1eb90a1 chore(gatsby-source-filesystem): fix jdoc (#22197)
  muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix        17dac01b7 fix
```

### git branch -avv

```
$ git branch -avv
* master                                                                   5a4f7a1e7 [origin/master: 60 hinterher] chore(starters): add gatsby-typescript-starter-minimalist (#23393)
  muescha/feature/npm-readme                                               f07b4db3c fix brand names
  muescha/fix/agility-format                                               06d9f8ad0 fix add language to code block
  muescha/fix/anchor-tags-in-glossary                                      505e5268e fixes links
  muescha/fix/brand-webpack                                                d0758d81f change brand names in yaml files
  muescha/fix/claudinary-code-block                                        b6eca1f0f fix add language to code block
  muescha/fix/claudinary-format                                            546fbdfc5 fix move out of prefix section
  muescha/fix/claudinary-optional                                          03d41affc fix move other optionals out of prefix section
  muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell                                           df7ad898c add shell
  muescha/fix/gatsby-cloud-brand-names                                     cad8ed156 fix brand names
  muescha/fix/la-days-kim                                                  623c6d28c change tags indent
  muescha/fix/receipes-changes                                             f788c2d0d change brand names, local links
  muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8                                                bf1eb90a1 chore(gatsby-source-filesystem): fix jdoc (#22197)
  muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix                                            17dac01b7 fix
  remotes/gatsby/100days-challenge-12                                      7f744f9e6 Fix typo
  remotes/gatsby/100days-challenge-12-branch                               7095e418b Expand on stale handling for gatsby sites (#22230)
  remotes/gatsby/100days-challenge-13                                      b08657ec8 Draft challenge 13
  remotes/gatsby/7z                                                        165bc0f09 restore apt install for circle, hopefully cloud wont randomly fail this time
  remotes/gatsby/Aswinpookkatt-patch-5                                     8a162cd2c fixed minor issue in docs
  remotes/gatsby/Blog-post-porting-jekyll-to-gatsby                        03e304ff2 �
  remotes/gatsby/DaleSeo-patch-1                                           5c577b6c3 Fix the image path
  remotes/gatsby/DaleSeo-patch-1-1                                         86c6bf76b Update remark-plugin-tutorial.md
  remotes/gatsby/KyleAMathews-patch-1                                      16010754d feat(gatsby-recipes): document option support for GatsbyPlugin
  remotes/gatsby/KyleAMathews-patch-2                                      2e40b6deb Update packages/gatsby-recipes/README.md
  remotes/gatsby/NotMoni-fix-whitespace                                    f2d27e72b fix whitespace
  remotes/gatsby/Olanetsoft-patch-2                                        2381fea7d Updated read-me with punctuation where necessary
  remotes/gatsby/PaulinaVPG/master                                         2f623924d Tested tutorial and left a few suggestions
  remotes/gatsby/Rizwanjamal-patch-1                                       6de1fbd25 docs: remove hidden code that no longer seen
  remotes/gatsby/Rizwanjamal-patch-1-1                                     618d4c642 docs: remove dead code
...
...
...
```

#### git remote -v show origin

```
$ git remote -v show origin
* Remote-Repository origin
  URL zum Abholen: https://github.com/muescha/gatsby.git
  URL zum Versenden: https://github.com/muescha/gatsby.git
  Hauptbranch: master
  Remote-Branch:
    master gefolgt
  Lokale Branches konfiguriert für 'git pull':
    master                         führt mit Remote-Branch master zusammen
    muescha/fix/agility-format     führt mit Remote-Branch muescha/fix/agility-format zusammen
    muescha/fix/brand-webpack      führt mit Remote-Branch muescha/fix/brand-webpack zusammen
    muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell führt mit Remote-Branch muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell zusammen
    muescha/fix/la-days-kim        führt mit Remote-Branch muescha/fix/la-days-kim zusammen
    muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix  führt mit Remote-Branch muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix zusammen
  Lokale Referenzen konfiguriert für 'git push':
    master                         versendet nach master                         (lokal nicht aktuell)
    muescha/fix/agility-format     versendet nach muescha/fix/agility-format     (aktuell)
    muescha/fix/brand-webpack      versendet nach muescha/fix/brand-webpack      (lokal nicht aktuell)
    muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell versendet nach muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell (lokal nicht aktuell)
    muescha/fix/la-days-kim        versendet nach muescha/fix/la-days-kim        (aktuell)
    muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix  versendet nach muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix  (aktuell)
```

#### git log origin/master..HEAD

```
$ git log origin/master..HEAD
# no output
```

#### git log --branches --not --remotes

```
$ git log --branches --not --remotes

commit 623c6d28c2792a24b147501a3e9e878aac54b04e (muescha/fix/la-days-kim)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 20 23:20:10 2020 +0200

    change tags indent

commit df7ad898c3149362bc385a427298cf3ad8431d63 (muescha/fix/docs-bash-to-shell)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Sun Apr 19 17:19:50 2020 +0200

    add shell

commit d0758d81f83c9a5e8ef5f1d1fb42f415bd6c9c4f (muescha/fix/brand-webpack)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Sat Apr 18 16:00:01 2020 +0200

    change brand names in yaml files

commit f788c2d0d472b62ce663a21e4d1a154fcde700ad (muescha/fix/receipes-changes)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Sat Apr 18 15:54:12 2020 +0200

    change brand names, local links

commit 06d9f8ad0853450c3dc7efc131331ca5da312e2f (muescha/fix/agility-format)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 15:19:36 2020 +0200

    fix add language to code block

commit b6eca1f0fb7cef6c8cbb937fd92a477220bdbbcb (muescha/fix/claudinary-code-block)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 08:58:38 2020 +0200

    fix add language to code block

commit 03d41affcd116272edb74961a6fae1c5e55ecf51 (muescha/fix/claudinary-optional)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 07:26:04 2020 +0200

    fix move other optionals out of prefix section

commit 546fbdfc58f7158b24507a6cbc73a70184c98e6c (muescha/fix/claudinary-format)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 07:23:43 2020 +0200

    fix move out of prefix section

commit 461e45ccb4e66c9b34ab857b4f14aaf973f3fe99
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 07:16:59 2020 +0200

    fix for lint/prettier

commit f07b4db3cf5ce3f78410db132892c8c99e9ca8b0 (muescha/feature/npm-readme)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 05:02:49 2020 +0200

    fix brand names

commit cad8ed156f712f774c7f31a8c6c340cdc1ce2a22 (muescha/fix/gatsby-cloud-brand-names)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 04:43:15 2020 +0200

    fix brand names

commit 7778482ef77d5bfd924b3d86ee97b5602ec42c63
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 01:14:13 2020 +0200

    fix 404 link

commit 1a0791afd2e4f4b35c7645c3725002aa8ed0b0b7
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 16 00:20:57 2020 +0200

    fix path to images

commit 5734a8c86736f2e670930f6e9c2bd71c10e77ced
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 15 23:48:09 2020 +0200

    fix file name

commit 10ee6e3b46ed7bec566f0323ebb79a88247db6e5
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 15 23:40:10 2020 +0200

    add links to TOC

commit 2983a4a1ee81e43c174fd0823b7487c769098d6d
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 15 23:14:48 2020 +0200

    fix frontmatter

commit 22e43a0e01032a377b3e6347967db6d4f3b75460
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 15 23:14:00 2020 +0200

fix frontmatter

commit fb08e2c9732d68dc1ce2cbf9a09159bf9229add5
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 7 22:45:25 2020 +0200

fix brand name

commit 99d7c9f0c45eae63a9b8ed291cda26acac67acae
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 7 21:29:20 2020 +0200

change bash to shell

commit 17dac01b7c640eb759d0788742323d9e38059aec (muescha/fix/tutorials-1-8-fix)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 12 14:42:07 2020 +0100

fix

commit 505e5268e81245ad3b8ce626100ef3fb02035455 (muescha/fix/anchor-tags-in-glossary)
Author: Muescha <184316+muescha@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 27 03:45:54 2020 +0100

fixes links
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
git branch -avv
```

You'll see all your local and remote branches with the upstream branch they are linked with.

`-a` or `--all` is for listing both remote and local branches

`-vv` allows to show the link with the remote branch

Comment: `git branch -vv` is probably more what the OP is looking for, if they're primarily trying to figure out what local branches don't have a corresponding remote branch.

Comment: He explained in his question that `git branch -vv` was not enough because it was showing only his local branch, so adding the `-a` allows to show also the remotes.

Comment: Mmm. Mismatch between the question title and the body I guess

Comment: i not see a title/body mismatch: i want a local branch and see the associated branch names at github in my repo. i added the expected results and the results of the suggested commands to show the differences

Comment: @Amber maybe there are some missing settings, that my remote branches are not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see all your local commits use:

```
git log origin/master..HEAD
```

In order to see all not pushed commits from all branches use:

```
git log --branches --not --remotes
```

Comment: it not shows the expected result `localbranch -> remote branch` - i updated my question with results

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use

`git branch -avv` which means:

`-a:` List both remote-tracking branches and local branches.

`-vv:` For verbose, or more detailed description